# Date format in SAS producing xxxxxx data

Tags: sas, sas-macro

When I am assigning a date variable to another new variable it is coming as all XXXX

so new_date = old_date where old_date was showing as 2021-09-09:00:00:00 but the new date in the new dataset is showing with all xxxxxx. I tried formatting it to date9. but no luck.

```
  sales_date = purchase_date;
```

Any advice?

I tried format date9.

Comment: "2021-09-09:00:00:00" is a kind of datetime formated value and "date9." is a date format, they are not matched. Try datetime format like "e8601dt.".

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored differently than datetimes by SAS.

That means you cannot apply date formats to a datetimes and vice versa.

Fortunately, SAS provides a couple of functions to deal with this situation. To extract the date value from a datetimes, you should use `datepart`:

```
data test;
  attrib a_dt format=datetime.;
  attrib a_d format=date9.;

  *-- Init datetime --*;
  a_dt = "08DEC2022:07:48:00"dt;

  *-- Extract date from datetime--*;
  a_d = datepart(a_dt);
  output;
run;
```